# Support twilio multiple incoming calls at the same time?

Tags: twilio

It's simple, I would like to use Twilio to connect calls with a different departments by a menu. This is simple.

But I would like to confirm if it's possible to receive more than one call at the same time and redirect to the correct number via Menu (if someone press 1 --> will be redirect to a XXX number, without hang out the first call, if the next person press 2 --> will be redirect to other number)

I am using  OpenVBX to manage the numbers and the workflows.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you get two calls on a Twilio number at the same time, you have nothing to worry about, they will be handled as two separate calls. So, if you build up a menu, then each call will go through it independently and be directed on to the number they choose from the menu.

I hope this helps, please let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Perfect. I have tried to confirm on their website but I cannot find the answer!.

Comment: any examples of this? Going by the original javascript documentation, there's the Twilio.Device.incoming function that accepts the connection parameter, but I'm not seeing how to handle multiple here...

Comment: @ganders This is for receiving calls on the same number but doesn't deal with. Once you receive a call on a Twilio number, you can do multiple things with it. I do not believe, however, that you can receive multiple calls to the same client ID at the same time. I would have thought, though I haven't tested, that a client that was already on a call would return a busy signal. If you're looking to deal with more than one call at a time with only one agent, then I recommend looking at TwiML's [Enqueue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue).

Comment: @philnash thanks for the response; that's not quite what I'm asking though. I'm looking at trying to be able to have two calls RING at the same time in an agents browser. Then the agent has the ability to ignore one call, while answering another.

Comment: Ah, I think the answer is still no, what we suggest is to use [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter) to turn incoming calls into tasks then offer those tasks to your agents to accept or reject, which can then trigger the call to the Client instance.